# NuSphere remote debugger dbg-php-5.3.so says it's not installed

Tags: php, apache, remote-debugging

just getting into php. Trying to get NuSphere remote debugging working. I am coming from VS background so i like that NuSphere is c compiled and not java.

Ok so if you use NuSphere maybe you can help me. I've dumped the dbg-php.5.3.so file in my extensions directory. I've modified my php.ini file:

```
zend_extension="/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/dbg-php-5.3.so"
[debugger]
debugger.enabled=on
debugger.profiler_enabled=on
```

the file is found.. except when i restart the webserver and run phpinfo (from my user account on a WHM/Cpanel server) the module does not show as being loaded??

I am using the trial version.. not sure if that matters.

Comment: Make sure you edited the correct phpinfo (i.e. the one used by the webserver, not the CLI).

Comment: how do i tell? I believe i am using the right one because when i tried to reboot it complained it couldn't find the .so file even though it was given the correct path. So.. makes me believe it was the correct one. I changed the .so version from 32 to 64bit and the complaint of httpd reboot was gone. But the module didn't load.

Comment: Seems you edited the correct file. No idea for a solution, though.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did:

1. Login to SSH and type php -i | grep php.ini

This will give you the path to the php.ini file you need to edit, on this system it happens to be /usr/local/lib/php.ini (Running CentOS 6 x86_64 with WHM/cPanel).

1. Edit /usr/local/lib/php.ini and search "extension_dir" which will give you the path to place dbg-php-5.3.so, on this system it happens to be /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626. Add the .so file there and continue to modify your php.ini file with the debugger options.
2. To test the the debugger is being loaded I restart httpd "service httpd restart" and then "php -v" to verify the extension loaded properly.

I hope this helps!